# In IB, I created a table and now want to assign a variable to it

Tags: iphone

I now want to refer to the table, but there isn't a variable in my .h file as it wasn't required when originally created.  The table works great, can add/display/etc.

I tried adding "myTable" to the .h and then linking in IB (the table was linked to "view" and I could/did select "myTable"), but my first try didn't work and I was afraid of messing up my (somewhat) working app ;-)

Hope the question makes sense!!!

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to link the table with your code. If that's the case, then in your header file you need to add a property like so

> @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet
>   UITableView *myTable;

And then synthesize it in your .m file like so

```
@synthesize myTable;
```

Once you've done that you will be able to link it up in interface builder. But bare in mind that if you want to populate/interact with the table further you need to set the data source/delegate of your table to your file's owner. Here is a tutorial on how to do that - http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/how-to-create-and-populate-a-uitableview

Does that answer your question?

Comment: thanks!  I knew I wasn't explaining it too good…

After reading all suggestions, I added the variable name and then linked the "Outlet" in IB to "myTableView" new variable.

Before when I tried to use IB, I deleted the "view" "Outlet" in IB as I didn't understand why I would want both ("view" and "myTableView") pointing to the "Table View" (still don't), but it does seem to work.

My .xib view simply has "Table View"/"UITableView".  I can't exactly remember how I originally created it, but it was the simplest option as I am just a beginner on all of this…

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
IBOutlet UITableView *    myTableView;
```

in your .h file i.e Declaration file.You can now access myTableView in IB.You can now create the object for this TableView.

Answer (score 0):

If your controller is a `UITableViewController`, just use its `tableView` property.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't entirely make sense because it's not clear what "the table works great..." means if you don't have any reference to it in your .h file. I'll assume you do have an iVar of class UITableView that is defined as an IBAction and you've implemented the table view dataSource and delegate protocols in your view controller implementation. If you have not then the table cannot display any data.

First, if you have an iVar defined you can just refer to the iVar directly. If you prefer a property you can create one.

If your view controller is a UITableViewController you don't need to do anything, the property `tableView` is already defined for you and you can refer to the table with the `tableView` property.

If your view controller is something else, you can create a property as follows in your .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)   UITableView *    myTableView;
```

and in your .m

```
@synthesize myTableView;
```

You can then refer to your tableView with:

```
self.myTableView;
```

Replace `myTableView` with the name of your tableView `iVar`. If you need to connect your tableView in IB to the myTableView property then instead define the property as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)   IBOutlet UITableView *    myTableView;
```

Once you've done this, edit your UI in IB and connect the tableView outlet to the `myTableView` property. You will also need to assign the tableView dataSource and delegate correctly. This is getting a bit beyond your question. Apple's Table View Controller Programming Guide has great docs on this.

Comment: thanks!  I knew I wasn't explaining it too good…

After reading all suggestions, I added the variable name and then linked the "Outlet" in IB to "myTableView" new variable.

Before when I tried to use IB, I deleted the "view" "Outlet" in IB as I didn't understand why I would want both ("view" and "myTableView") pointing to the "Table View" (still don't), but it does seem to work.

My .xib view simply has "Table View"/"UITableView".  I can't exactly remember how I originally created it, but it was the simplest option as I am just a beginner on all of this…